# SQL Tables - Count rows of table1 based on other 2 tables' conditions

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, join

> My problem is I want to count all the students **under *n* department**.
>   *Note: Students has a course and courses has their department (there are many courses in 1 department).*
>   SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
+---------+-------------------------------+
| student | department                    |
+---------+-------------------------------+
|       23| Computer Education Department |
|       67| Basic Education Department    |
|       39| Mathematics Department        |
|       40| Humanities Department         |
|       61| Engineering Department        |
|       79| Management Department         |
+---------+-------------------------------+
```

1. *tbl_students*

```
+---------+---------------+--------+
| stud_id | name          | course |
+---------+---------------+--------+
|       1 | Jack Owen     |      1 |
|       2 | Kirby Lopez   |      2 |
|       3 | Justin Minus  |      1 |
|       4 | Jerome Noveda |      1 |
+---------+---------------+--------+
```

*2. tbl_courses*

```
+-----------+------------+---------+
| course_id | short_name | dept_id |
+-----------+------------+---------+
|         1 | BSIT       |       1 |
|         2 | BSCS       |       1 |
|         3 | BEED       |       2 |
|         4 | BSED       |       2 |
|         6 | BSTHRM     |       7 |
|         7 | BLIS       |       4 |
|         8 | BSCE       |       6 |
+-----------+------------+---------+
```

*3. tbl_department*

```
+---------+-------------------------------+
| dept_id | full_name                     |
+---------+-------------------------------+
|       1 | Computer Education Department |
|       2 | Basic Education Department    |
|       3 | Mathematics Department        |
|       4 | Humanities Department         |
|       6 | Engineering Department        |
|       7 | Management Department         |
+---------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: This looks like homework. Have you tried anything yourself to solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried JOIN statement?

Comment: Yes, I tried joining the 3 tables and I can't figure out the right condition to match want I want. I tried the ANSI method on joining tables and the old way(just select the 3 tables) and I can't figure it out. Btw, this isn't a homework I'm working on my own project and I'm stuck with this problem.

Comment: @MuTiny Yes, But I can't figure out the right condition.

Comment: Because it has also something to do with the count sql syntax you just have to count all the students in the department by the use of the department id.

Comment: 1rst, MySQL and SQL-Serveur tag.. Witch one are you using? https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/1008/join#t=201706130829020707819

Comment: [link](https://prnt.sc/fj5qa4) my query.

Comment: You can use the [Edit] button on your question if you want to add information. Picture of code is always an issue.

Comment: @DragandDrop I don't know how to join 3 tables so I use the old method of joining i.e. just selecting tables and comparing.

Comment: The Documentation has some perfect exemple of how things work. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/topics. I recommend the getting start, and join part

Comment: @DragandDrop Okay I dig into this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
    tbl_department.full_name as department,
    COUNT(DISTINCT tbl_students.stud_id) AS student
FROM
    tbl_department
    JOIN tbl_courses
        ON tbl_department.dept_id = tbl_courses.dept_id
    JOIN tbl_students
        ON tbl_courses.course_id = tbl_students.course
GROUP BY
    tbl_department.full_name
```

Comment: This was all I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
ISNULL(( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_courses C
  INNER JOIN tbl_students S ON C.course_id = S.course
  WHERE C.dept_id = D.dept_id
),0) AS student
,D.full_name AS department
FROM
tbl_department D
```

I hope that it will work for you.